# How to get mod_auth_openidc_session id using python?

Tags: python-3.x, web, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I am a complete beginner for requests library and web scraping. When I want to scrape a website, it scraped data as expected. But, it is not scraping data when session id ends. I used chrome cookies to scrape the data from that website.

What I need is, if it is possible to get the mod_auth_openidc_session id, I can use it whenever a session ends. If it is possible, please give me the python code to get it.

Please let me know if any further clarification needed. Thanks in advance.

I need the python code to get the mod_auth_openidc_session of a website.